# out of memory c# List<>

Tags: c#, list, out-of-memory

I use List<> to store data call from database to print in printdocument.
But when row is more than 300, **OutOfMemoryException** occurs.
Any solution to clear the memory? or any other method to add data to the list?

```
private List<FormName> printItem = new List<FormName>();
public string printItemCode;
public string printPartNo;
public string printIssued;
public string printUOM;

//call from database
using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        FormName item = new FormName()
        {
            printItemCode = rdr[0].ToString(),
            printPartNo = rdr[1].ToString(),
            printIssued = rdr[2].ToString(),
            printUOM = rdr[3].ToString(),
        };

        printItem.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: How many of those columns are `varchar(max)`? Also, how much RAM do you have?

Comment: @Nisarg just calling 4 from 20 columns in Access database. I'm using 4GB RAM with 64-bit OS

Comment: What is SelectPreviewIR? You may be running on a 64-bit os, but that doesn't mean your process is 64-bit. What architecture are you compiling against?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. Two likely causes jump to mind. a) You are never clearing `printItem` and thus it continually grows as you run your code repeatedly. b) Some of your values are very large (check this by checking `rdr[0].ToString().Length` and also for `1`, `2` and `3`).

Comment: Maybe add `item = null;` after `printItem.Add(item);'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved by using a class instead of FormName.

```
private List<Items> printItem = new List<Items>();

class Items
{
    public string printItemCode { get; set; }
    public string printPartNo { get; set; }
    public string printIssued { get; set; }
    public string printUOM { get; set; }
}


using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        Items item = new Items()
        {
            printItemCode = rdr[0].ToString(),
            printPartNo = rdr[1].ToString(),
            printIssued = rdr[2].ToString(),
            printUOM = rdr[3].ToString(),
        };

        printItem.Add(item);
    }
}
```